# In MongoShell: Not able to connect to my collection, db.collection_name return NaN

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I am using MongoDB Enterprise, MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5

I have a db = mydb and a collections = ['events', 'events__2015-12-01', 'events__2015-11-01']

I have a python/pymongo script where I can connect to every document but in mongo shell I cannot to connect to the dated collections?

in other words

```
mongodb> use mydb 
switched to db mydb
mongodb> db.event
mydb/event
mongodb> db.event__2015-12-01
NaN
mongodb> db.event__2015-11-01
NaN
mongodb> show collections
event
event__2015-11-01
event__2015-12-01
```

why does this happen in the shell?

EDIT:

Note: On further inspection [Mongo Documentations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restriction-on-Collection-Names). Clearly states that collections with special characters can only be accessed via getCollection() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `db.event__2015-12-01`, `event__2015-12-01` is your collection object which is quite different from the elements in your collections array or list (Python).

To create a collection object from string, you need to use the [`getCollection()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.getCollection/) method in the shell and the [`get_collection()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.get_collection) method in your Python script. You can use the `[]` operator as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of following syntaxes to access collections with hyphenated names:

```
db['event__2015-12-01']
```

OR

```
db.getCollection('event__2015-12-01')
```

Comment: Ya Correct !! Please follow @Jagdeep Singh statements.